# Bootloader is messed up, keyboard doesn't work, and fast boot is enabled so USB isnt loading

Tags: grub2, bootloader

I am in a bit of a predicament.

I was trying to change the default boot order in grub on ubuntu which messed up grub. Now I get booted into grub minimal bash mode and the keyboard won't work regardless of the USB port I use. Also it won't boot from USB because fast boot is enabled. What can I do? I am on a gigabyte motherboard with dual boot enabled for Ubuntu and Windows.

Clearing the CMOS by opening the mobo and shorting the cmos pins reset the boot order and fixed it.

Comment: Try clearing cmos by re-seating battery

Comment: So a hardware reset of the BIOS? I think I found a way for my specific motherboard on youtube. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fGpf_hfOKgI&feature=emb_title

Comment: Find another computer, create a LiveUSB, then boot from there and google how to restore grub from a live usb

Comment: It won’t boot from USB because fast boost disables USB booting